Recently added translations don't reach the site (part III)
A week ago I did some translations on ru.traducir.win, in particular this pair. They are visible on transifex, but for some (same as earlier?) reason don't reach the site. I still see English in mod panel:



8 days ago Adam mentioned that all such things were fixed: Recently added translations don't reach the site again
Maybe we faced with something new but with an old behavior?
UPDATE
12 hours after my original post, translation has appeared on site. Despite that I will leave this report since that according the description provided here translation updates should not take so much time.

As I said in the other post, it's minimum 12 hours, but can take longer. There's no technical problem here, but the human parts of the process can take time. Specifically, this translation was merged 3 days ago, but we didn't have a prod build until yesterday.

What "human parts" you mean here? A PR review? I expected that updating translations doesn't require manual work from staff side.

@αλεχολυτ PR reviews and production builds are manual. The PR review step is new with this process, but the builds were always manual, so no change in the process there. I'm not super happy about adding another step like that, but it's the best we can do at the moment.

Did I understand you correctly, now a bunch of new translation comes from Transifex (since the last check) and that creates a separate PR to be approved by staff?

@αλεχολυτ Yes, that's correct.
